# C#. Как заставить форму перемещаться удалив у нее рамку?

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день. Подскажите как заставить форму перемещаться удалив у нее рамку?
Тоесть у меня у MainForm выключен ControlBox и BorderStyle - None
И форма не двигается теперь.. Как вернуть возможность перемещать ее? Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg==0x84)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if ((int)m.Result == 0x1)
                m.Result = (IntPtr)0x2;
            return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Добавьте этот метод.

Answer (score 2):

Код взят с англоязычного SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592876/make-a-borderless-form-movable.

Определите `onMouseDown` слушателя на форму, и вставьте следующий код.

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{     
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}
```

В результате получается по сути делает то же самое, что и захват строки заголовка окна у обычной `winform`